# Extract sections from range found in word document

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Below code works fine, we got start and end point which needs to be extracted but im not able to get range.set/select to work

I'm able to get the range from below, just need to extra and save it to CSV file...

`$found = $paras2.Range.SetRange($startPosition, $endPosition)` - this piece doesn't work.

```
$file = "D:\Files\Scan.doc"
$SearchKeyword1 =  'Keyword1'
$SearchKeyword2 =  'Keyword2'    

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($file,$false,$true)
$sel = $word.Selection 
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs 
$paras1 = $doc.Paragraphs
$paras2 = $doc.Paragraphs

foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword1)
    {
        Write-Host $para.Range.Text
        $startPosition = $para.Range.Start
    }
} 
foreach ($para in $paras1) 
{ 
    if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword2)
    {
        Write-Host $para.Range.Text
        $endPosition = $para.Range.Start
    }
} 

Write-Host $startPosition
Write-Host $endPosition
$found = $paras2.Range.SetRange($startPosition, $endPosition)

# cleanup com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: $found= $doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition).Select() 
Write-Host $found

Doesn't print anything, don't know how to export this to csv or doc file

Comment: If $found is not $null, try something like `$found.Text | Out-File "C:\Found.txt"`

Comment: And what do the `Write-Host` statements for the start and end positions return?

Comment: 90945, 94679 - Write host print these numbers @CindyMeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is the problem

```
$found = $paras2.Range.SetRange($startPosition, $endPosition)
```

When designating a Range by the start and end position it's necessary to do so relative to the *document*. The code above refers to a `Paragraphs` collection. In addition, it uses `SetRange`, but should only use the `Range` method. So:

```
$found = $doc.Range.($startPosition, $endPosition)
```